# Azure DevOps Pipeline for iOS - Fastlane Match Clone Problem

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-devops, fastlane

I'm trying to implement iOS pipeline to Azure DevOps using Fastlane. I have already have Fastlane in my project and successfully deploy beta and pilot versions. My problem is that when I run below script on Azure pipeline, It can't pass `match` clone part. Therefore, can't fetch certificates, provision profiles etc..

**P.S: iOS_Certificates repo is different than project repo.**

I'm getting timeout error after 1 hour. I think It is about authentication to

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- script: |
    fastlane match development --clone_branch_directly --verbose
    fastlane beta
  displayName: 'Build iOS'
```

Related code in MatchFile:

```
git_url("git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/myteam/myproject/certificates_repo")
storage_mode("git")
type("development")
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to fetch a repo inside **same project** inside Azure DevOps (not GitHub or somewhere else). I'm getting timeout error, so no specific error even I run `--verbose` on match command.

Comment: Can you share the error message when running this script? Is the repo you cloned from azure devops github or something else？What method did you use as the authentication method for cloning？ If you are using Azure Repo, you could try to set the [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) as the authentication method. Please share more information about this issue so that we can better understand the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: On the other hand, you could check if [this ticket](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5537) could give you some help.

Comment: I added more information. @KevinLu-MSFT

Comment: Hi @Emre Önder. Thanks for your information. I tried to use the same url `git@ssh....` and got the same error. The job cancelled after 60 minutes without any error message. I have share some suggestions in the answer , please check if it could make some changes.

Comment: Hello. I still can't figure out. I'll let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information, you are using the SSH key as the authentication method.

Since you are using the `macos-latest`(microsoft-hosted agent) as build agent, the private key of ssh key will not exist on the target build machine.

So it can't authenticate and gets stuck. As you said, it will run 60 minutes and cancel. I could also reproduce this issue.

You could try to create [a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) and run the build on it.

In this case, you need to ensure that the private key exists on the machine， then you could authenticate through the ssh key.

On the other hand,  you can authenticate with username and password.

For example(matchfile):

```
git_url "https://organizationname@dev.azure.com/organizationname/projectname/_git/reponame" 
type "development" 
app_identifier 'xxx'
username "member@companyname.com" #This will be the git username
ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "abcdefgh" #Password to access git repo.
ENV["MATCH_PASSWORD"] = "password" #Password for the .p12 files saved in git repo.
```

Comment: Using https for checkout worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup access to this second repository through `resources` block:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition

And then access it though HTTPS using the `System.AccessToken` as access token to you repo:`https://[AZURE_TOKEN]@dev.azure.com/[org]/[project]/_git/[repo]`